# How to retrieve values from a checkbox group generated dinamically with jquery when page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, checkbox

I need to get the values of the checked checkbox of 2 group of checkbox. These 2 groups aren't in the html file but they are generated with jquery when the page is loaded. I need 2 functions `getSubjects()` and `getDates()` that return the values of the relative checked checkbox group.

The HTML and JS that I use to generate them:

```js
function loadAvailable() {
    $.ajax({
            url: "Controller",
            type: "POST",
            data: {action: "load"},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                $("#listAvailable").html("");
                var courses = getCourses(result);
                
                if(courses.length == 0){
                    var sorry = "Some text.";
                    $("#listAvailable").text(sorry);
                }
                $("#subjects").html("");
                addDates(result);
                var len = courses.length;
                for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
                    var course = courses[i];
                    addCourseCheckbox(course, "#subjects");
                   //other stuff
               }
            },
            error: function (xhr, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
}

function addDates(data){
    $("#days").html("");
    var res = new Array();
    var i;
    var len = data.length;
    for(i=0; i<len; i++){
        var date = data[i].date;
        if(!res.includes(date)){
            res.push(date);
            var d = new Date();
            d.setTime(date);
            addDateCheckbox(d);
        }
    }
}

function addCourseCheckbox(course) {
   var container = $("#subjects");
   var inputs = container.find('input');
   var id = inputs.length+1;

   $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', 
                    id: 'ccb'+id, 
                    name: 'subject',
                    value: course, 
                    class: 'checkSub'}).appendTo(container);
   $('<label />', { 'for': 'ccb'+id,
                     text: course }).appendTo(container);
}
//                   
function addDateCheckbox(data) {
    var container = $("#days");
    var inputs = container.find('input');
    var id = inputs.length+1;
    $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', 
                     id: 'dcb'+id, 
                     name: 'date',
                     value: data.getTime(), 
                     class: 'checkDay' }).appendTo(container);
    $('<label />', { 'for': 'dcb'+id,
                     text: shortDate(data)}).appendTo(container);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<aside id="filter">
            Filtra le disponibili&agrave;:<br>
            Data<br>
            <div class="filter" id="days"></div>
            Materia<br>
            <div class="filter" id="subjects"></div>
            <button onclick="filterAvailable()">Filtra</button>
        </aside>
```

I tried in Vanilla JS like this:

```js
function getSubjects() {
    var x = new Array();
   [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="subject"]:checked'), function(cb) {
   x.push(cb.value); 
});
    return x;
}
```

and I tried this too:

```js
var x = new Array();
$('input[name="subject"]:checked').each(function() {
   x.push(this.value);
});
return x;
```

And this other version:

```js
var x = $('input[name="subject"]:checked').serialize();
return x;
```

But nothing seems to work.

P.S. I used `getSubjects()` here as example and not both because they are equals.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had it right except that this.value should be $(this).val() because you are looping through JQuery version of elements;

here is the code:

```
function getData(groupName){
    var x = new Array();
    $('input[name="'+ groupName +'"]:checked').each(function() {
       x.push($(this).val());
    });
    return x;
}
```

to call it....

```
getData('subject');
getData('date');
```

Comment: i'm glad I was able to help. Please accept the answer so others can helped too.

Comment: Click on the checkbox next to the answer. I believe it is green in color. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Accepted. Just one more thing. To make it work with several groups of radiobutton (grouped by name attribute) always created dinamically? How?

Comment: i have updated the answer. now the same function can be used for any number of checkboxes (group of).

Comment: And for group of radio? Does it work? Or it works only for group of checkboxes?

Comment: Will work for both. As a matter of fact you will not have a group of checkboxes with same name, that is a functionality of radio buttons.